# Obtener imagen de perfil de un usuario de twitter tras autentificación PHP de oAuth

Tags: php, oauth, twitter

Necesito saber cómo obtener la imagen de perfil de un usuario que se acabe de loguear en mi website mediante twitter oAuth. Necesito la imagen en full size, por lo que profile_picture_url no me sirve (ya que devuelve una imagen de 48x48. Necesito la imagen de tamaño original. Éste es mi código:

```
<?php

if(!isset($_SESSION)){
    session_start();
}

require 'autoload.php';

use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;

define('CONSUMER_KEY', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'); // add your app consumer key between single quotes
define('CONSUMER_SECRET', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'); // add your app consumer secret key between single quotes
define('OAUTH_CALLBACK', 'http://www.chapatelo.com.ar/chm/peticiones/callback.php'); // your app callback URL
if (!isset($_SESSION['access_token'])) {
    $connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
    $request_token = $connection->oauth('oauth/request_token', array('oauth_callback' => OAUTH_CALLBACK));
    $_SESSION['oauth_token'] = $request_token['oauth_token'];
    $_SESSION['oauth_token_secret'] = $request_token['oauth_token_secret'];
    $url = $connection->url('oauth/authorize', array('oauth_token' =>     $request_token['oauth_token']));
    header("Location: " . $url);
} else {
    $access_token = $_SESSION['access_token'];
    $connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET,     $access_token['oauth_token'], $access_token['oauth_token_secret']);
    $user = $connection->get("account/verify_credentials");

    $_SESSION["id"] = $user->id;
    $_SESSION["usuario"] = $user->screen_name;
    $_SESSION["start"] = time();
    $_SESSION["expire"] = $_SESSION["start"] + (3600 * 60);

    echo '<img src="' . $user->profile_image_url. '"/>'; //Obviamente, este echo muetra una imagen demasiado pequeña...
}

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás utilizando la propiedad equivocada, deberías utilizar:

```
profile_image_url
```

ó

```
profile_background_image_url_https
```

**Edición 1:**

Ahora, con respecto a que la imagen esta muy pequeña, lo que debes hacer es jugar con los valores, mira las siguientes URLs:

https://abs.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_6_normal.png

https://abs.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_6_bigger.png

https://abs.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_6_mini.png

https://abs.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_6.png

Espero te haya dado las ideas necesarias para que logres lo propuesto :D

Revisa la documentación: https://dev.twitter.com/overview/general/user-profile-images-and-banners

**Edición 2:**

Lo que nos devuelve profile_image_url es:

```
"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/a2.twimg.com\/profile_images\/1438634086\/avatar_normal.png"
```

que al visualizar la url se ve como:

```
 "http://a2.twimg.com/profile_images/1438634086/avatar_normal.png
```

Ahora lo que debes hacer es mediante la funcion `replace` de `PHP`, cambiar ese `_normal` por el tamaño que estás buscando: `_bigger`, `_mini`, o simplemente eliminar el `_normal` -> este último te dará el tamaño original de la imagen.

Comment: Pero me muestra la imagen más chica. Necesito la imagen en tamaño de al menos 200 x 200 px. Alguna idea?

Comment: respuesta actualizada :D

Comment: mmm casi, pero me aparece la imagen de un huevo, no la imagen de perfil de la persona logueada con twitter en mi página....

Comment: Yo pregunté como sería con el ID y el Screen_name que el oAuth me proporsiona

Comment: es proporciona. Acabo de actualizar la respuesta, veo que también encontraste una manera alternativa de hacerlo, que sigan los éxitos y dale con todo el power 2.0 al desarrollo!

Answer (score 0):

He deducido una forma SUPER sencilla de conseguir la foto de perfil del usuario logueado con oAuth, simplemente haciendo lo siguiente:

```
$imgSrc = substr($user->profile_image_url, 0, -11);

$imgSrc .= ".jpg";

echo '<img style="width:200px; height=200px;" src="' . $imgSrc . '"/>';
```

¿Cómo funciona?

Básicamente, lo que hice es imprimir en pantalla **$user->profile_image_url** para ver cual era la url que me mostraba. Y me di cuenta que siempre termina en "_normal.jpg". Por lo cual solo le sustraje esos caracteres, luego le añadí ".jpg" a la cadena (para que muestre la imagen originalmente subida), y finalmente la puse de "src" de la imagen. De esta manera, me apareció una imagen full HD para poder customizar a mi antojo.

Espero que esto ayude a muchos que buscan como hacer lo mismo, pero que lamentablemente nadie sabe ayudarlos de la manera que necesitan...